# Get in PHP an output value and a recordset from a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have the following procedure in MySQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCustomerData`(
IN customerId INT(11),
OUT totalValue INT(11)
)

BEGIN
  SELECT id,name,category,quantity,price,tax,total FROM product WHERE 
  customer_Id = customerId;
  SELECT SUM(total) INTO totalValue FROM product WHERE customer_Id = 
  customerId;
END
```

In phpMyAdmin the procedure returns both the recordset and the sum into totalValue.

The issue that I'm facing is to get all this information in PHP. I'm able to get the recordset or the totalValue parameter but not both. This is the code that I have tried with different variations for the mysqli functions:

```
$query = "CALL getCustomerData('".$customerId."',@totalValue);";
$query.= "SELECT @totalValue";

if(mysqli_multi_query($dblink,$query)){
  $values = array();

  do{
     if($result = mysqli_use_result($dblink)){
        while($this->row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           $values[] =  $this->row;                    
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
      }else{
           throw new \Exception(mysqli_error($dblink));
      }

      if(!mysqli_more_results($dblink)){
         $values['test'] = "No more results found";
      }
   }while (mysqli_next_result($dblink));

   return $values;
 }
 else{
     throw new \Exception(mysqli_error($dblink));
 }
```

I added the mysqli_more_results function to test if there's more info to get and it always return true. mysqli_use_result doesn't work for the output value.

I also added this:

```
if(mysqli_next_result($dblink)){
   $select = mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT @totalValue');
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
   $values['totalValue'] = $result['@totalValue'];
}
```

after the recordset was fetch, without the do-while loop, but no luck...
In this part I'm getting a

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in customer.php on line <i>8
```

Is it possible to get this mix (recordset + output value) in PHP? If so can anyone shed some light here.

Thank you,

Comment: what is `@totalValue ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use the OUT-parameter for the second result set?

It would be easier just to return two result sets from the procedure. This way both result sets would be handled in the same way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getCustomerData`(
customerId INT(11)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT id,name,category,quantity,price,tax,total 
  FROM product 
  WHERE customer_Id = customerId;

  SELECT SUM(total) as totalValue 
  FROM product 
  WHERE customer_Id = customerId;
END
```

And you can call the procedure from PHP:

```
$query = "CALL getCustomerData(".intval($customerId).")";

if (mysqli_multi_query($dblink,$query)){
  $values = array();
  do {
    $result_set = array();
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($dblink)) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_set[] = $row;                    
      }
      $values[] = $result_set;
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
  } while (mysqli_more_results($dblink) && mysqli_next_result($dblink));

  return $values;
}
else{
 throw new Exception(mysqli_error($dblink));
}
```

Comment: How do you call this from PHP? The only way that mysqli_multi_query is working in PHP is if I build the query with the two selects instead of using the CALL query.

Comment: See example PHP code. The result sets will be stored as separate array elements into the $values.

Comment: This works thanks a lot! I found two issues with my code that I think they shouldn't fail: the first one is that I can't throw the exception after the inner if-else. mysqli_store_result returns FALSE however there are records... and the second one is that I have to call mysqli_more_results just before mysqli_next_result.

Comment: You can mark the answer to be useful (upvote it). Might help someone else.

Comment: Yep, marked as useful. My vote is not displayed yet.. my reputation doesn't meet the 15 required to display them :-(